How to make method for pandas.to_sql for making update operation?
I got some tables in database, which must be updated.
How to perform this with table.to_sql for Postgresql, v.16.2?
Run .to_sql with if_exists='replace' will not works, cause this table related to another.
I now that I can make custom method for this, but I can't find working code or good explanation hot to do it.
Edit:
My best shot is this method:
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

def pg_upsert(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    for row in data:
        row_dict = dict(zip(keys, row))
        stmt = postgresql.insert(table).values(**row_dict)
        upsert_stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
            index_elements=table.index,
            set_=row_dict)
        conn.execute(upsert_stmt)

But then I use it:
table.to_sql(
    'table', 
    con=engine, 
    schema='public', 
    if_exists='replace', 
    index=False, 
    chunksize=200,
    method=pg_upsert
    )

I get error:
DependentObjectsStillExist: can't delete table, cause there' data that depents of it.

And hint:
HINT:  use DROP ... CASCADE.


Per to_sql use 'append'?

I don't think .to_sql, or Pandas for that matter, is designed as a DB client (update, delete, etc...). Pandas is mostly designed to be in-memory data manipulation. You should resolve to a dedicate db client to do so.

So which library better use for this update operation?

@JohnDoe pandas uses asyncpg so you can try using that directly, or try psycopg3. But I think you can just switch if_exists='replace' to if_exists='append' as per Adrian's suggestion above. The if_exists mode refers to the whole table, so your choice of replace instructed pandas to try and drop the whole thing first, which gave you that error.
